# Sending data (variable) from windows command line to the php webpage

Tags: php, matlab, curl, cmd, system

I am new in php. I want to post some data as an input to the php page from the command line of the windows.
In fact, I use MATLAB via system(curl) command to post some string as the input to the php file. I want to use this string in the body of the php and write it to some file and then read that file with matlab.

Here is my code in matlab (I want to run matlab code to run php in behind and then given back to me in matlab two data (time and given string):

```
command = strcat('curl',{' '},'--data "name=ii"',{' '},'http://sample.com/a.php');
[~,cmdout] = system(command{1});
expression = '(http://).*(.dat)';
[~,matches] = regexp(cmdout,expression,'tokens','match');
url = matches{1};
command = strcat('curl',{' '}, url);
[~,cmdout] = system(command{1})
```

And here is my code in php (a.php):

```
<?php
parse_str($diff[1], $_GET);
print $diff;
$filename='http://sample.com/a.dat';
$t_now=time();
$list=array($t_now,$diff);
$file=fopen($filename,'w');
foreach ($list as $line)
{
    fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
}
fclose($file);
echo "
<html>
    <body>
        <a href=$filename target='_self'>Ok</a>
    </body>
</html>";
?>
```

Comment: do you receive any output or have an errors log to include?

Comment: I don't know if my code is true or not. but without error, I earn only one data (time) with matlab calback and the other (given string) can not be earned.

Comment: In fact I don't know two things: 1. giving input to the php via matlab with: '--data "name=ii"'     2.earning data in php with: parse_str($diff[1], $_GET);....       These are my 2 unknowns.

Comment: What is the output of cmdout on the second line?

Comment: cmdout =

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   132  100   128  100     4    154      4  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01   162hhhhhhhhhhhhh210154
<html>
    <body>
        <a href=http://sample.com/a.dat target='_self'>Ok</a>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: If you want to get the `ii` string, modify a.php add `echo $_REQUEST['name'];` before `echo "HTML...`, then re-try to see cmdout.

Comment: Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in execution

Comment: So how do you want to parse that response @AsgFar? Because that expression is looking for a http url

Comment: i download attached file to the a.php (a.dat) and read its content with matlab. a proper value of "time" (the first data) is read, but the second data (the string that i send with matlab to the a.php that it should store it in the same file -a.dat- can not be stored in the file and hence, matlab can not read it.

Comment: clearly i don't know how to send (from matlab or windows cmd) and receive data (from a.php)?