# put data to php page with matlab code (via cmd windows)

Tags: php, matlab, curl, cmd

I don't know how to giving input to the php via matlab:
system('curl -d "a=ii" http://creativeelite.ir/a.php') does not work.

send data or string to the a.php from command line windows (via matlab) is my challenges. In fact, i don't know how can i post some data or string to the php page.

Comment: Did you have a working Apache with PHP local server. If you had, make sure you enabled php_curl PHP extension. Then, to catch the `a` param, you can you `$a_val = $_GET['a']` in the `CheckLisence.php` file.

Comment: I don't work with Apache. I run matlab code and want to post a data to the a.php with system(curl) command. But I don't know how to can do this in matlab.

Comment: Yes, that's your problem. You need a local server can run PHP to make curl and your a.php file work. And, actually, you don;t send data to your a.php file, you are sending data to http://creativeelite.ir/CheckLisence.php

Comment: please see:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692433/sending-data-variable-from-windows-command-line-to-the-php-webpage

Comment: i want to do that without any local server. here, i can read php's one data (time), but i can't read posted data (string) to php with matlab.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of your previous question: [Sending data (variable) from windows command line to the php webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692433/sending-data-variable-from-windows-command-line-to-the-php-webpage). Please stop spamming very similar questions!